I can't remove the background choir
I can't remove the background choir from my audio track. I have tried various methods using Audacity and Spleeter, but the choir remains too prominent. Here is the link to the audio file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_i-t2qCJrFeJ8H4oky_uRYoFkaca5SnI/view?usp=sharing]. Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

My advice is come up with a plan B. Mixes are often like cakes: you can’t unbake them and separate the eggs, flour, sugar, etc.
